# Is it possible to get lastUser for a DHIS2 analytics API call?

Tags: api, analytics, dhis-2

We're running a nodeJS script to identify erroneous data values (negative numbers) and we're unable to determine which user captured the values without logging in and inspecting the data entry form.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation for including user identification data in the analytics API end point.

Has anyone figured this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

many APIs are present in dhis2 documentation including these :

```
/api/33/dataValueSets
/api/33/dataValues
```

But a more suitable API for this case would be the AUDIT API:

```
/api/33/audits/dataValue
```

A detailed documentation is visible at this link :
https://docs.dhis2.org/en/develop/using-the-api/dhis-core-version-235/web-api.html#webapi_auditing_aggregate_audits